# execute a shell script and all its commands as a specific user

Tags: linux, centos7

I have a shell script `myShell.sh` and it runs the following commands in it:

`docker run --name sample_container sample_image:tag`

I want to run this script AS WELL AS the **command** as a specific user - user1.

I tried this:
`sudo -u user1 "path_to_my_script/myShell.sh"`

**ps -ef results:**

```
user1  9471  9469  0 18:53 pts/1    00:00:00 /bin/bash /usr/libexec/myShell.sh
root   9522  9520  0 18:53 pts/1    00:00:00 docker run --name sample_container sample_image:tag
```

As can be seen, the script runs as user1, but the command runs are root user.

I want to run both the script AND its commands as user1 user. Do I have to run each command inside the script by prepending **sudo -u user1**? Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: How do you call the commands in the script? When you start a script all commands in it are started as that user.

Comment: Apart from that, what do you mean by `user1 has root privileges`? You can't give another user `root privileges`. You can at most give a user permissions to become root.

Comment: Edited my question to show command and ps -ef output. W.r.t. user permissions, my bad. What  I meant was user1 has sudo permissions to execute commands

Comment: That docker command in your `ps` output has not been executed by  `myShell.sh`. It has been launched by the process with the ID `9520`, and the fact that the PID is lower than the PID of the shell script suggests that it has been launched before you started the script.

Comment: Most probably you already have a container with the name `sample_container` running, and the docker command inside your script failed because the name was already in use.

Comment: https://medium.com/redbubble/running-a-docker-container-as-a-non-root-user-7d2e00f8ee15